# How can I merge SharePoint spaces?

Tags: sharepoint

My team has accumulated several SharePoint spaces over the years and we would like to merge them.  How can I do that?

Comment: No OOTB feature can achieve this as per my knowledge, you may ask for help from 3rd party tools.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box option for consolidating SharePoint site collections together.  There are however [several](https://www.nucleustechnologies.com/blog/5-best-sharepoint-content-migration-software/) migration tools to choose from.
Having used all of these, personally, I would recommend [ShareGate](https://sharegate.com/) as the most user friendly for this kind of consolidation.